# What is the "arg" field value that is sent on woocommerce_add_to_cart webhook?

Tags: json, rest, woocommerce, webhooks, woocommerce-rest-api

I would like to know whether an addition of a product to a cart occurred on woocommerce. On the documentation it says that an application should consume a webhook that notifies about a `woocommerce_add_to_cart` action.

So I implemented it and gladly got a message saying it happened a short while after such an event occurred.

Here's an example JSON I got from woocommerce:

```
{"action":"woocommerce_add_to_cart","arg":"fe9fc289c3ff0af142b6d3bead98a923"}
```

However since many visitors of a woocommerce website may have their own cart, and many products, I would like to know if there's a way to decode the arg field so that it will provide a unique product that was added to a specific cart.

In case I am using the wrong method in order to learn about an addition to a cart, I would be happy to learn which one may be better for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **'arg'** value **is the cart item key** that is passed through `woocommerce_add_to_cart` action hook as an argument, **and that is returned** on `WC_Cart` [`add_to_cart()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_add_to_cart) method [**on line `1120`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#1120):

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data );

return $cart_item_key; // <========= HERE
```

That **cart item key** allows you for example **to get the cart item** using `WC_Cart` [`get_cart_item()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_get_cart_item) method and retrieve the cart item data:

```
$cart_item = WC()->cart->get_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
```

Comment: Thanks for your thorough reply LoicTheAztec :-)
Now, I get the arg field within a java program that accepts webhooks notifications, so extracting a cart item or the whole cart info is not something that I know how to reach within my program.

Do you know of a way to reach this info from a REST client?