# How to use woocommerce webhook woocommerce_add_to_cart "arg" JSON value at third party application (with REST API) to request a woo commerce product?

Tags: rest, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, navision, dynamics-business-central

In the process the development of the syncronization solution between onprem Navision (through REST api) and WooCommerce.

Would like to keep Woo commerce product stock info up to date.
I do not know what to do with the "arg",recieved from woocommerce_add_to_cart webhook response:

woocommerce_add_to_cart webhook response:
{"action":"woocommerce_add_to_cart","arg":"fe9fc289c3ff0af142b6d3bead98a923"}

The Main question is what are repro steps call the WP function (WC_Cart get_cart_item()) to get the product by "arg":"fe9fc289c3ff0af142b6d3bead98a923" (CartPrtoductId) on the 3rd party api.

I saw this post but there is no full answer.

[What is the "arg" field value that is sent on woocommerce_add_to_cart webhook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55673045/what-is-the-arg-field-value-that-is-sent-on-woocommerce-add-to-cart-webhook)

I consider whether one webhook may be used to send added to cart "cart product Id"  (woocommerce_add_to_cart) to the second (WC_Cart get_cart_item()) which in turn will send the response as the Product JSON tho the 3rd party API.
I guess the first webhook may send the data directly to the second and the second to the REST API If that's possible of cause.

Regards,
Denys